# How to sort by letter in Django

Tags: html, django, if-statement

On my website, there are different listings arranged as (a-e), (e-j), (j-o), (o-t), and all. When a user clicks on any of these listings, I want the website to retrieve data from the database starting with titles that fall within the selected letter range. However, I'm not very familiar with how to implement this functionality. Can anyone help me with this?

index.html

```
<div class="widget-content">
    <h4>Sort by letter</h4>
        <ul class="widget-links">
            {% for letter_range in letter_ranges %}
                {% if selected_range == letter_range %}
                    <li><strong>{{ letter_range }}</strong></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a href="?range={{ letter_range }}">{{letter_range}}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    letter_ranges = ['All', 'a-e', 'e-j', 'j-o', 'o-t', 't-z']
    selected_range = request.GET.get('range', 'All')

    if selected_range == 'All':
        queryset = tabir.objects.filter(is_active=True)
    else:
        start_letter, end_letter = selected_range.split('-')
        queryset = tabir.objects.filter(title__istartswith__range=(start_letter, end_letter), is_active=True)

    context = {
        "tabirs": queryset,
        "current_date": datetime.now(),
        "selected_range": selected_range,
        "letter_ranges": letter_ranges,
    }
    return render(request, "ruya/index.html", context)
```

models.py

```
class tabir(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = RichTextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_home = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    release_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False,blank=True) #default=datetime.date.today
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(editable = False, auto_now_add=True)#default=datetime.date.today
    slug = models.SlugField(null= False, blank=True,unique=True, db_index=True, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `__range` on the [**`Lower`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#lower) of the field:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

letters = selected_range.split('-')
queryset = tabir.objects.alias(title_lower=Lower('title')).filter(
    title_lower__range=letters, is_active=True
)
```